# Mongoose: Find and update an object in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema here:

```
const assetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  symbol: String,
  amount: Number
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: String,
    budget: Number,
    assets: [assetSchema]
  })
```

I try to use it to simulate stock trading. I have users in database and their stocks record in an array.
Like this:

```
{
"user": "John", 
"budget": 10000, 
"assets": [{"symbol":"TSLA", "amount": 5}, {"symbol":"AAPL", "amount": 10}, ........ ]
}
```

How can I find a particular object in assets array by its symbol, and update it? {"symbol":"TSLA", "amount": 20} for example.
or how to redesign my schema would be better?

Comment: From the marked duplicate answers, use the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in your update e.g. `await User.findOneAndUpdate({ user: 'John', 'assets.symbol': 'TSLA' }, { $set: { 'assets.$.amount': 20 } }).exec()`

Comment: Thank you, it works!! @chridam